# GET variables not passed when mixed in with URL

Tags: php, html, forms

Why is it that when I pass parameters through encoded URL and GET method in HTML form, the URL encoded parameters are dropped?

e.g. Setup:

```
<form action="process.php?hello=world" method="GET">
<input type="text" name="foo" value="bar">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Result: the variable `hello` will not be recognized in `process.php`.

Is this bad practice?

Is this how PHP processes it, or is it related to how the browser send the request? Is there the same problem in other languages?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but doesn't this result in a URL of the form: `process.php?hello=world?foo=bar` (with two question marks)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, that is bad practice because it just doesn't work.

If you want to pass in "hidden form input" then you must use a hidden form element:

```
<input type="hidden" name="hello" value="world" />
```

As rezzif states in his comment, you can mix GET & POST like so:

```
<form action="/something?foo=bar" method="POST">
<input type="text" name="baz" />
</form>
```

As a general rule I avoid mixing the two though. I find it bizarre to have GET params in my form action.

Comment: You can however mix get and post.